# Multithreading: more efficient to have static variables with a static Lock or non-static variables and then compare the results between all threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, thread-safety, locking

I have a list of files, let's say of size 1000.
Each thread is going to do some work on 100 files, so we would have a total of 10 threads.
The result of this work, for each thread, is an int and a String.

I thought basically about two approaches. The first one:

```
private static int maxConfidence;
private static String bestMatch;
private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();


public void run()
{
...
lock.lock;
if(tempConfidence>maxConfidence) 
{
       maxConfidence=tempConfidence;
       bestMatch = getCurrentString();
}
lock.unlock();
}
```

The second one:

```
private int maxConfidence;
private String bestMatch;
private boolean isFinished


public void run()
{
...
ìif(tempConfidence>maxConfidence) 
{
       maxConfidence=tempConfidence;
       bestMatch = getCurrentString();
}
isFinished = true;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
if(allThreadsAreFinished())
{
getMaxConfidenceAndBestMatchBetweenThreads(threadsArray);
}
}
```

As you can see, in the first case scenario, there is a lock when checking and assigning the results. So, when all threads are finished we have already the best result.

In the second case scenario, each thread has his own results for the chunk of files he worked on. When all threads are finished results for each thread are compared and the best match with max confidence is chosen.

Comment: Have you already benchmarked both approaches?

Comment: @aled I did not. I wanted to hear out from the community first. Maybe they have suggestions on which approach would be preferable.

Comment: There won't be a definitive answer here since it all depends on how often the locking will occur. In theory if your locks will occur often and other threads will wait for that lock then the second approach would be faster but on the other hand it could happen that first approach would be faster. It also will depend on scale, for 10 threads with 100 files in each the difference will probably be so small that this problem shouldn't be considered as problem. So my advice would be to benchmark both approaches. Also while benchmarking remember to run this operations more than once

Comment: Since java will do optimizations and it could happen that one or the other solution will be faster on first run but on the second and so on could be slower than the other one